# Hibernate Save/Update Cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

There is a class A like:

```
class A {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Basic(optional = false)
     @Column(name = "DBId")
     private Long DBId = null;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     List<B> list;
}
```

and a class B like

```
class B {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Basic(optional = false)
     @Column(name = "DBId")
     private Long DBId = null;
}
```

When I want to persist a new instance of class A, two cases are possible.
1- All instances of B in A are new, in which case, a simple session.save(A) is ok.
2- Some or all of the instances of B in A are old. How should I save A in order not to have duplicate Bs. Will saveOrUpdate solve the problem? or it will just decide to choose save or update just by looking at A, and for example if A was new, it will also call save on Bs, and if A was old, it will also call update on Bs?

Furthermore, I saw that I had just a simple session.save(A) in my codes, and it did not produce redundant Bs. Am I wrong? Is this possible?

Regards

**UPDATE:** in case of old Bs, the instances of old Bs are attached to the session, and DBId is correctly set.

Comment: You should look at the Hibernate traces: if SQL traces are enabled, you'll see exactly all the SQL sentences Hibernate generates to know what to do with Bs.

Comment: Yes, I think saveOrUpdate should help you. Did you try this?

Comment: Not yet. But why didn't save make problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your entities live longer than sessions? If not, you don't have to use `update()` or `saveOrUpdate()`. When you call `session.save()`, Hibernate knows whether to `insert` or `update`, by checking the state of the entity. You can read here for more about states: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview

The same applies to the cascade. When the operation is cascaded to the collection, Hibernate will check the state of the entities in the collection and will **NOT** try to insert them, if they are already in `PERSISTENT` state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, In the link it is mentioned that "If a parent is passed to save(), update() or saveOrUpdate(), all children are passed to saveOrUpdate()"